# cannot login with administrator account on windows server 2012 on some machines

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am the administrator of a *Windows Server 2012 R2* network in our enterprise . I can login with my administrator account into some machines but cant do so on other machines.
does anyone have any idea of why this is so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved , we had different wifi networks and when  the a computer is in the wrong network we cant login with administrator account